# Merge two tables in power Query Excel

Tags: powerquery

I have two tables one with data shown below

**Table A**

| Name | location |
| --- | --- |
| A | Bangalore , India |
| AB | Kuwalampur ,Singapore |

I'm trying to merge table A with Table B

**Table B**

| City | Country |
| --- | --- |
| Bangalore | India |
| Singapore | Singapore |

I used Fuzzy lookup but the rows multiply, is there a better way to do in power Query

Comment: split table A column location on commas into separate rows. Then merge Table A with table B using left outer join (Table B top, Table A bottom) and expand

Comment: @horseyride It worked . Thanks a lot